# NSLog returning nil outside (id)

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nslog

I'm trying to access `_urlS` outside `initWithURL:`. If I NSLog inside it, I get a value but if I `NSLog` it in `websiteload:`, I get `(null)`.

Really strange, anybody any ideas?

.h file:

```
@interface WebsiteViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UIWebViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate> {
    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    UIBarButtonItem *barButton;

    NSString *urlWeb;

    IBOutlet UIWebView *Website;

    UILabel *testLabel;

    IBOutlet UIButton *btn;

    IBOutlet UILabel *lbllong;

    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIPopoverController *popoverController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *barButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *urlS;

- (void)addBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc;
- (void)removeBarButtonItem;

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)postURL;


@end
```

.m file:

```
#import "WebsiteViewController.h"

@interface WebsiteViewController ()

@end

@implementation WebsiteViewController

@synthesize barButton, popoverController;
@synthesize urlS = _urlS;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (id)initWithURL:(NSString *)postURL
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _urlS = [[postURL stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
        [lbllong setText:_urlS];
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)websiteload:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"%@", _urlS);


}

- (void)addBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)barButtonItem forPopoverController: (UIPopoverController*)pc {

}
- (void)removeBarButtonItem {

}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Please show your interface .

Comment: U are using MRC, so your urlS is released. retain it.

Comment: Anoop Vaidya is absolutely correct.

Comment: AmiiQo: Please show us how `_urlS` is defined in your .h file.

Comment: A part from the fact that you miss the `-dealloc` method, so every instance of that class will leak, can you try to `NSLog` `lbllong` in `websiteload`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I know the -dealloc is missing... If I NSLog lbllong.text I just get the text I put there manually

Comment: The code you have shown so far is correct from a memory managment point of view. The only explanation is that you have an extra `release` on `_urlS` somewhere else.

Comment: Log the value of `self` in both the `-initWithURL:` and `-websiteload:` methods. Perhaps you are dealing with two different instances of your class.

Answer (score 3):

You need to retain the object when assigning it, since
`stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:` returns an autoreleased instance and therefore it gets released since you don't own it.

Change the assignment to

```
_urlS = [[postURL stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] retain];
```

Comment: I was't sure about this, so i commented :p

Comment: I answer at the same time :) It used to happen to me a lot before ARC.

Comment: Well thanks for your effort but it seems like it still returns (null) :(